# How can I save uploaded image using Laravel Spatie medialibrary v9?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-medialibrary

I'm trying to save my uploaded file using Spatie's media libray (v9) and somehow I can't persist the image in my media table and my storage folder. When i dd() the request it finds the file and every information it needs, what am I missing ?

Here is my controller store method :

```
 public function store(Request $request, User $user) {

    
    $validationToken = Str::random(32);

    $user->create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'validation_token' => $validationToken
    ]);

    if($request->file('avatar')) {
        // persists the uploaded file into the media table
        $user->addMediaFromRequest('avatar')->toMediaCollection('avatars');

        // fills the avatar column in user table with image path
        $user->update(['avatar' => $request->file('avatar')]);
    }

    session()->flash('message', 'L`utilisateur a bien été créé');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

}

And my Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements HasMedia
{
use Notifiable, InteractsWithMedia;


public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null): void
{
    $this->addMediaConversion('thumb')
        ->width(368)
        ->height(232)
        ->sharpen(10);
}

// allows to delete previous avatars when new one is submitted with singleFile() method
public function registerMediaCollections(): void
{
    $this
        ->addMediaCollection('avatars')
        ->singleFile();
}
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: `$user->update(['avatar' => $request->file('avatar')]);` does this section works? What does the `$request->file('avatar')` returns?

Comment: it didn't work, however I just found what was wrong, I'm uploading the answer !

Answer (score 0):

Well, just found the answer, I was actually really close.

The addMediaFromRequest() method must be called on the $user->create() and not on the model itself.

```
public function store(Request $request, User $user) {


    $validationToken = Str::random(32);

    $createUser = $user->create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'validation_token' => $validationToken
    ]);

    if($request->file('avatar')) {
        $createUser->addMediaFromRequest('avatar')->toMediaCollection('avatars');
        $createUser->update(['avatar' => $request->file('avatar')]);
    }
}
```